# ORA-06550 error when trying to create PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Something is off but can't figure out what I am missing?

```
 select 
        grade.sectionid,
        grade.studentid,
        course.courseid
    FROM section
        INNER JOIN grade
                ON grade.sectionid = section.sectionid
        INNER JOIN course
                ON course.courseid = section.courseid;




DECLARE
   CURSOR mycursor is
      select 
        sectionid, studentid, courseid, coursename
      FROM grade, course, section;      
   var_secID NUMBER(10);
   var_studentID NUMBER (10);
   var_gradeLetter CHAR(1);
   var_coursetitle VARCHAR2(25);


BEGIN
   OPEN mycursor;
LOOP
      FETCH mycursor 
      INTO var_secID, var_studentID, var_gradeLetter, var_coursetitle;
      EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND;  
      If var_coursetitle(coursename,1) BETWEEN A AND F then
      UPDATE grade
        SET grade = 'A'
        WHERE sectionid;
        END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE mycursor;
END;
/
```

Keep getting this error:

ERROR at line 21:

ORA-06550: line 21, column 18:

PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

ORA-06550: line 19, column 4:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: A join in the cursor definition `....... FROM grade, course, section; ` creates a cross join of three tables (generates all posiible combinations of all rows from these three tables), so I am not quite sure what do you want to achieve using this query.

Comment: I have created a trigger to populate grades into my GRADE table. I am wanting the procedure to look at the last letter of the student's course name and assign a grade (A-F) depending on that last letter. Does that help clarify?(this is my first time working with databases or SQL so I am still very new and trying to get things figured out).

Comment: Towards the end you have `... UPDATE grade ... WHERE sectionid;`  What does that mean? Where sectionid **what**? Something is missing there.

Comment: As mathguy mentioned, the compiler is expecting a relational operator following `where sectionid`, for example `where sectionid = var_secID`.

Answer (score 1):

```
BETWEEN A AND F then
```

should perhaps be:

```
BETWEEN 'A' and 'F' then
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without any PL/SQL, as:

```
update grade g set grade = 'A'
where  g.sectionid in
       ( select s.sectionid from section s
                join course c on c.courseid = s.courseid
         where  substr(c.coursename,-1, 1) between 'A' and 'F' );
```

However as a PL/SQL learning exercise, you could do it without any of the variable or cursor management:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select g.sectionid, g.studentid, c.courseid, c.coursename
             , substr(c.coursename,-1, 1) as course_lastchar
        from   grade g
               join section s on s.sectionid = g.sectionid
               join course c on c.courseid = s.courseid
        for update of grade
    )
    loop
        if r.course_lastchar between 'A' and 'F' then
            update grade set grade = 'A' where sectionid = r.sectionid;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

(btw it's worth getting into the habit of laying code out neatly with a consistent indent size.)